# Checking in scalar-valued functions of sql database to git

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-synapse, azure-synapse-analytics

I have an Azure SQL database solution, and I'm trying to check it into git; however, I'm trying to add two scalar-valued functions that return table objects, and they're not showing up as new objects when I use schema compare in visual studio. Please see the following screenshots:

1. I'm trying to add three functions; one is returning an int and the other two are returning tables:
   [image]
2. When I do the schema compare, only the one returning an int is showing up:
   [image]

I'm expecting for all three functions to show up in the schema compare as they are all new objects.